# Is Chapter 2 of Time Fcuk just the level Cecil?

Tags: the-basement-collection, time-fcuk

When I complete the level Cecil, I get a message saying "Ending 3" and the same cutscene you get for taking a pill in "Dead End".

What's going on here? What am I missing? The main "Basement Collection" claims I did *not* finish the game, but I did sleep through two levels in "Chapter 1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. Try saving, exiting, reopening the game, and then playing chapter 2. Or wait until the next patch.

From [Edmondm's site](http://edmundm.com/):

> Time Fcuk Ch2 bug:
>   There is a lame big in ch2 of time fcuk where if you complete the game and play ch2 right away it only lets you play 1 of the 33 levels in ch2. to avoid this bug exit time fcuk and then come back and play ch2.
>   this will be fully patched monday either way.

Comment: Now I _wish_ it was just the level Cecil :D

Comment: I still experienced this bug yesterday